# sets and Indices in cplex c++ concert tech

Tags: c++, cplex

I have the following sets and indices in my formulations. I am not able to declare it in cplex c++ concert technology. Should I consider "*Nsd*" as two dimensonal matrix ? What about  γ , N(γ)  and  A(γ) ? Advance thanks for any help.

```
N  = set of nodes

A  = set of arcs

s  Є N  =  index used for  sources

d  Є N  =  index used for  destinations

Nsd  =  set of acceptable paths that connect  s and d.

 γ Є Nsd  = index used for network paths

N(γ)  = set of nodes along path γ

A(γ) = set of arcs along path γ
```

Comment: You will likely get better feedback if you show your code (i.e., what you have tried so far).  Also, if you haven't already, you should peruse the C++ examples that are shipped with CPLEX.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback but  I am in initial stage of my coding.

Answer (score 0):

Like @rkersh commented it would be better if you provide a piece of your code. In any case, if I understood correctly you are not sure on how to declare and use a set of variables with 2 indexes.

If that is really the case you could use the following piece of code to declare a new type that would fit represent 2-dimensional matrix of variables

```
typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> NumVarMatrix;
```

Then to declare your variables you could use something like

```
NumVarMatrix variable_name(env, number_of_rows);
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
        variable_name[i] = IloNumVarArray(env, number_of_columns, 0, 1, ILOINT); // ILOINT or any other type that you see fit
```

I suggest that you take a look at the example file `facility.cpp` which comes with cplex so you can see a full working example.

There are many other examples shipped with cplex that are very helpful to give you an overview of what you can do and how.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur feedback. I will follow ur suggestions